# Sum of two different folders

Tags: command-line, disk-usage

I am trying to use the du command to find the total size of multiple folders and print the total in a single line. It works but I would like to sum them up automatically and print the total size.

This is what I am doing currently:

```
du -h -c directory_1|tail -1 && du -h -c directory_2|tail -1
160K    total
35M     total
```

How do I get to print the sum of both the directories. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-s` option will just show the total. From `man du`:

```
-s, --summarize
       display only a total for each argument
```

Without `-s`, `du` will also list each sub-directory individually. In combination with this, you can just use both directories as arguments.

```
du -shc directory_1 directory_2
```